# Convert large character into word frequency matrix for Gephi in R

Tags: r, twitter, frequency, tm, gephi

I want to calculate pairwise word-frequencies of a large number of tweets I have collected. So that  I can use them for visualizsation in Gephi (network graph). The current data looks like this (it is a character).

```
head(Tweet_text)
[1] "habits that separates successful persons from mediocre persons habit success startup entrepreneurship"                 
[2] "business entrepreneurship tech watch youtube star casey neistat ride a drone dressed as santa"        
[3] "how to beat procrastination work deadlines workculture productivity management hr hrd entrepreneurship"
[4] "reading on entrepreneurship and startups and enjoying my latte"                                        
[5] "not a very nice way to encourage entrepreneurship and in the same sentence dog another company"        
[6] "us robotics founder on earlyday internet entrepreneurship articles management"
```

The structure is as follows:

```
str(Tweet_text)
 chr [1:8661] "habits that separates successful persons from mediocre persons habit success startup entrepreneurship" ...
```

In this sample data set, I have 8661 tweets. Now I want to calculate pairwise word frequencies over all these tweets that I can export to Gephi. The end-result I am looking for is the following:

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+
| term1                  | term 2       | Freq |
+------------------------+--------------+------+
| entrepreneurship       | startup      |  2   |
+------------------------+--------------+------+
```

So I started to use the DocumentTermMatrix function in the tm package:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Corpus(VectorSource(Tweet_text)))
```

This worked (see below frequency of "success" in the first tweet):

```
inspect(dtm[1, c("success")])
<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 1, terms: 1)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 1/0
Sparsity           : 0%
Maximal term length: 7
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

    Terms
Docs success
   1       1
```

After this I tried to put these frequencies in the desired table format with:

```
m<-as.matrix(dtm)
m[m>=1] <- 1
m <- m %*% t(m)
Dat_Freq <- as.data.frame(as.table(m))
```

But now the first problem starts, that the matrix is just far too big. Next to that I do not know how I can restrict the pairwise-wordfrequencies to a specific value. For examle a pair needs to have a frequency > 10, so that the matrix does not get to large.

Would appreciate your advise on that, how I can get these pairwise-frequencies in a csv format.

All the best :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thing you can do is use the [tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/index.html) package.

Let's say that your data are in a dataframe called `tweets` and `text` is the corresponding variable

```
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)

tweets %>%
   unnest_tokens(bigram, text, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
   count(bigram, sort = TRUE) %>%
   head(100)
```

will give you the 100 most frequent bigrams. Of course it might be a good idea to remove stopwords first so take a look at the recipes in the [Tidy text mining book](http://tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html)

Comment: Thanks Yannis P.! I did not know this book before, so I will for sure check that out. I will comment, if I have found the solution :). And yes, you are right, I need to clean the stopwords first.

Comment: Had found some time to check, and the tidytext library works perfect for pairwise word frequencies! Thanks Yannis!

Comment: Seems to be the new 'go-to' for text processing in R

Comment: Yes it is quite nice. I like the one-token-per-document-per-row idea compared to the other approaches from the tm libraray for examples with TermDocumentMatrix etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check RWeka library especially the NGramTokenizer() function. It will allow you to get all the pairwise words possible. Then you should use the findFreqTerms() function to select only terms > 10.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will directly check if that works. :)